# How do I create a icon for my program executable file in C#?

Tags: c#, icons

I did some Googling but all results point to Icons from the left top of the program.

How can I change the icon of my program so if it sits on desktop it has a nice look to it?

Regards.

Comment: Do you have a icon file and you just want to use it, or do you need to also create the icon file?

Comment: I do have an icon already created with extension *.ICO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Visual Studio solution explorer, right click your main project > select bottom option, properties > on the bottom of the page you will see project icon and manifest, browse for the icon you want to use.

Hope that helps.

Corby

Answer (score 0):

in the properties of your project, in 'Application' tab, you can set your icon. It must be a .ico file, but you have online converters that will do the job to get them from .png to .ico for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your icon probably just needs to have a higher resolution layer. Use this [online converter](http://iconverticons.com/) with your source image with at least 128x128 resolution. It will build the proper Windows icon set - no matter the bit depth of the client (32, 16, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

You can add a higher-resolution icon for the desktop using your installation program.

Answer (score 0):

I created an Icon using a 3d software, after rendering the image, I open it in Gimp and I saved it as an Icon file, to do so click File -> Export, in the Export Image dialog box type the name for your icon and as the file extension type .ico (yourIcon.ico). Gimp is a open source program.